# Unity line renderer poor anti-aliasing

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity 2018.3.8f1, I'm using a standard line renderer and noticed that when not horizontal or vertical, the edges become jagged. They appear this way in play mode and a build at Ultra quality.

I've tried enabling/maxing anti-aliasing in the quality settings but it has zero effect here. I've tried playing with width, vertex counts, adding points, etc.

Even when adding curves for a cubic bezier, the edges are still jagged.

I'm just not sure what else to do. The lines look awful.

[image]

Comment: Are these lines in a Screen Space Canvas by any chance? Then this may be related: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139626/is-ui-anti-aliasing-broken-in-unity-5-6

Comment: No they're in world space

Comment: I'm not sure about your setup, but it could be worth a shot to try the post processing stack's FXAA. Here is the post-proc stack docs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessing-Stack.html